# Way to automatically download or print attachments or URLs from emails with specific labels

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-attachments

More and more companies are sending electronic invoices.

- Some do so by attachment,
- others by embedding an URL to an on-line location.

  - For URLs, some require login or cookie, some don't.

I'm looking for a way to automate my Gmail so that for mails I (manually or automatically) mark with a certain label (like save-files or print-files) the files will be either saved, or printed.

Where should I get started?

I can put up a Windows VM behind firewall for this if needed.

Download probably suffices, as from there I should be able to print.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nifty service called **[IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/)** (which stands for "**If** **T**his **T**hen **T**hat") that, among *many* other things, will allow you to create "Recipes" to automate certain tasks within certain "Channels".

Here's an example of an [IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/73746-save-starred-gmails-to-evernote) that saves "starred" Gmail attachments to an Evernote account. (Gmail and Evernote are just 2 of more than 160 "Channels" within IFTTT.)

And [here's a recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/126725-emails-you-label-to-do-get-added-to-an-ios-reminders-list) that adds Gmails labeled "To-do" to an iOS Reminders list.

Comment: IFTTT is awesome. I have a recipe that saves any PDF attachment where it finds "receipt" in the message body to my Google Drive.

Comment: @AlE. can you share that recipe?

Comment: @Jeroen: Here's someone else's: [Save electronic receipts to Gdrive](https://ifttt.com/recipes/96152-create-a-new-document-in-gdrive-when-you-receive-a-digital-receipt-in-your-gmail-drive-gmail-rec). A quick search for "[receipt](https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=receipt&ac=false)" offers a bunch of other likely candidates.

Comment: Also, here's a link to the (currently) 775 recipes involving the terms "Gmail Google Drive": https://ifttt.com/connect/gmail/google_drive

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers: Not mine, but [this applet](https://ifttt.com/applets/96152p-create-a-new-document-in-gdrive-when-you-receive-a-digital-receipt-in-your-gmail-drive-gmail-rec) purports to do the same thing. Tweak as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a programmatic/browser-only answer, as I believe any method that doesn't rely on ANY installed software could only be accomplished by building a Gmail add-on, a nontrivial task. But if you have Outlook for Desktop, you could set up a fairly simple [Google Script](https://script.google.com) to autoforward all threads under a certain label to a secondary email in your Outlook, then use the more powerful VBA scripting to extract/save attachments to local storage. Here's an example of the Google Script:

```
function autoForward() {
  var label = '<yourlabel>'; //replace "<yourlabel>" with the label of emails to target
  var recipient = '<me@myemail.com>'; //replace "<me@myemail.com>" with your destination email address
  var interval = 5;          //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:' + label) + ' after:' + timeFrom + 'has:attachment');
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].getMessages()[0].forward(recipient);  // only the 1st message
    threads[i].markRead(); // mark each forwarded thread as read, one by one
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(threads); //change this to 
  }
}
```

In Outlook for Desktop, set up your secondary email (you can even create a [free Outlook.com email address](https://outlook.com) then [sync it via POP3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040) to Outlook for Desktop), then you have a lot more powerful tools like VBA macros. Then create a macro (may require adding the Developer tab to the toolbar, via Customize This Ribbon). Use this code to autosave attachments from emails:

```
Private Sub DownloadAttsFromSelection()
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim mi As MailItem
    Dim Atts As Attachments
    Dim Att As Attachment
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strName As String
    For Each mi In myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Items
       Set Atts = mi.Attachments
       If Atts.Count > 0 Then
          For Each Att In Atts
            'Replace "test" with what you want to look for in attachment name
            If InStr(LCase(Att.FileName), "test") > 0 Then
              'Use your wanted destination folder path to save the attachments
              strPath = "C:\Attachments\"
              'Use your wanted destination folder path to save the attachments
              strName = NewMail.Subject & " " & Chr(45) & " " & Att.FileName
              Att.SaveAsFile strPath & strName
            End If
          Next
       End If
    Next mi
End Sub
```

Set this macro to run automatically (anytime your Outlook is open, at least) by going to Home > Rules > Manage Rules & Alerts > New Rule > Email Rules. In the popup, select "Apply rule on messages I receive". After clicking Next, check the box for "run a script" and select the VBA script you just created. Finish creating the rule.

ALTERNATIVELY, you could use a Google Script like gmail2gdrive ([source code](https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive)) to save attachments to a folder in your Google Drive, then use either [Google Backup & Sync or Google Drive Desktop](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7638428?hl=en) to sync it with a folder on your local drive.

Comment: Not using Outlook (I'm on multiple platforms so try to keep this all web based), but I like the gmail2gdrive suggestion. Need to give it quite a bit of thought. Is not going to happen soon given my situation (see profile).