# How to download attachments of Gmail mail automatically?

Tags: gmail, gmail-attachments

I receive mail every day with some attachments and I want to download those attachments automatically when they arrive to my mail box. Is that possible? and if yes, how?

Comment: What email program do you use? Microsoft Outlook automatically does this. Thunderbird too.

Comment: I use a couple of different [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) applets to save certain files to my Google Drive. Since I also use the Google Drive sync client, the files are automatically downloaded to my hard drive.

Comment: I'm sorry, without knowing what mail client you use, we can't provide a useful answer. Could you please [edit] your question with all relevant details? Note that if you just use the web client, your question should go on [webapps.se].

Comment: Related: [Way to automatically download or print attachments or URLs from emails with specific labels](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/73308/354)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Save Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-emails-and-attachmen/nflmnfjphdbeagnilbihcodcophecebc) addon for Google Sheets. It runs as a background trigger that connects to Gmail in the background and automatically downloads the email attachments to Google Drive.

You can install the Google Drive client on your Windows PC / Mac and the drive file will instantly become available on your local disk.

(disclosure: I am the author of the Google addon)

Comment: After testing, Amit's solution is limited with the free version and the upgrade is $29 per year.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an app called [Unattach](https://unattach.app/), which allows you to easily download Gmail attachments in bulk, and optionally remove them. It currently doesn't have a mode to run at a regular interval, but that could be added quite easily if needed.